# Pass Object from one fragment to another fragment when recyclerView item is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, parcelable

My MainActivity hosts 4 fragments. All the fragments are recycler views but 3 have a details fragment. I have the class below to implement recycler view click listener.

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);    
        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onLongItemClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {}

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (boolean disallowIntercept){}
}
```

In my Series Fragment, I implement it like so

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
    new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            mListener.onSeriesSelected(series, position);
            Series series = seriesList.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), series.getTitle() + " " + series.getId() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {}
}));
```

Now, I want to open a SeriesDetail fragment when the recyclerView is clicked and pass the Series object of that recycler view to the
SeriesDetail fragment.

I read that the Series model must implement Parcelable which I did with the help of an IntelliJ plugin and that I would need to implement an interface in the Series fragment.

```
public interface onSeriesSelectedListener {
    void onSeriesSelected(Series series, int position);
}
```

And override the onAttach method in the fragment which I did like so

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the listener interface. If not, it throws an exception
    if (context instanceof onSeriesSelectedListener) {
        mListener = (onSeriesSelectedListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
 + " must implement onSeriesSelectedListener");
    }
}
```

And finally, override the interface in the MainActivity which I did like this

```
@Override
public void onSeriesSelected(Series series, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new SeriesDetailFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    bundle.putParcelable("seriesDetail", series);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
}
```

Now in the onCreate method of the SeriesDetail fragment, I am supposed to access the Parcelable object like so

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Series series = bundle.getParcelable("seriesDetail");
        if (series != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), series.getTitle() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("Series", "Title:" + series.getTitle());
        }
    }
}
```

Yet, I do not get the object at this point. What I'm I doing wrong? Please help me!!! I've been at this for hours. Thank you

Comment: Put some `Log` in your code to see *how far* your command chain goes. Does it reach `onSeriesSelected`? By the way, in that method you call `setArguments` twice - once before it gets the data and once after. This is not the cause of your problems though.

Comment: It is a bit over the top, I think, to use `Bundle` for Activity-Fragment communication (although your code is from developer.android.com). Since your activity has a reference to the fragment and your fragment has `context` you can make direct calls. However, I can confirm that your approach works. Therefore the question is if there is something wrong with your touchListeners or with your parcelization. Use the `Log` approach from my first comment to find out.

Answer (score 0):

```
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener (new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), 
     recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Series series = seriesList.get(position);  
        mListener.onSeriesSelected(series, position);                      
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {}
    }));
```

The listener was firing before the series position could be gotten thereby making Series null in MainActivity. Thank you for your help.